Understanding complex square root branches
I just have a doubt about this, if I consider $\displaystyle \int_{C} z^{1/2}dz$, my tutor computed the integral for the principal branch $f_1=\lvert z \rvert^{1/2} e ^{\frac{i \theta}{2}}$, my question basically is the following, if I consider $f_2= \lvert z  \rvert^{1/2} e^{i(\frac{\theta}{2} + \pi k)}, k=0,1$, can I say this is the other branch? Or am I completeley misunderstanding what branches are. Thank you!

Can you please edit the question to clarify: Are you asking how to write two branches of complex square root? (If so, does the integral need to be mentioned?) Or are you asking about integrating some branch of square root, possibly non-principal? <> If it matters, a branch of square root is not just an algebraic expression such as $f_1$ or $f_2$; it's crucial to specify a domain.

I'm sorry, the integral was not necessary to mention, just interested in understanding the branch cuts of  the square root

Does the answer here help?
